# Scrapy: how to access -o (output) argument written in terminal command

Tags: python, csv, scrapy, scrapy-pipeline

I'm making my own custom pipeline in scrapy project and you want access to `-o` argument so I can use it in naming my exported file in the new pipeline:

```
scrapy crawl hotels -o hotels_file.csv --loglevel=ERROR
```

I want access to `hotels_file.csv` for further use in my code

any help please ? thanks in advance :)

Comment: You want to use it inside your spider or for some other script. Usually, we avoid any analysis work insider spiders.

Comment: but why is that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access from the spider by getting the value for 'FEED_URI' from the settings, like this:

```
filename = self.settings['FEED_URI']}
```